# My questions and answers are missing from my profile page

Tags: bug, status-declined

I have asked a few questions and answered some questions too, but when I click my profile name on top, I get this screen. 
How can my reputation be 213, without asking, answering any questions.

[image]

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Shouldn't this be [meta-tag:status-bydesign], not [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @hichris123: Not sure, it should "status-not-a-bug", but this tag does not exist, so I guess I wanted to say that I decline the fact that it's a bug.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset [meta-tag:status-bydesign] means `Indicates that a submitted issue is actually due to the existing design of the system and is not considered erroneous behaviour.` So, I'd say by-design, since it's not a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you checking your [account from meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12632/ank)? If so, your reputation is linked to your reputation on the main site. 
When checking your [account on the main site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/12632/ank), I can see your questions and your answers.